# Can an Adobe Flash advertisement capture user account name and password for a site hosting the advertisement?

Tags: flash, security, adobe, ads

I believe the newest style of Flash-based advertisements might be a security risk.

Have you ever seen a little Flash animated advertisement dance across some site page your visiting? Usually it's something rather clever and mildly entertaining, a ball bouncing around, a car driving around, or some video of a person doing something to grab your attention. generally covering up the very thing your interested in reading. These are quite clearly advertisements.

However, I just came from a site where the Flash advertisement perfectly overlaid, and masked content on the host site. Now the advertisement itself was of course coming from a 3rd party site, so it was indeed quite clever of the designers to get pixel perfect precision of the current content, overlay images and static content, and then create a fancy breakout animation. What was *not* pleasant is that I was totally unaware that the animation, advertisement was running.

During that time, I clicked within fields to login to the site and autonomously typed my username and password (while also glancing up and watching television). When I looked back down, no text was visible in the fields. I clicked them again and tried typing. Nothing showed up. Then the advertisement played its animation.

Obviously, the advertisement had overlaid everything on the page, and I'd been clicking focus into the Flash application itself. I know from my own Flash application development that the app was perfectly capable of recording my keypresses while it had focus. So...

Anyone have experience creating these sort of "clever" Flash advertisements? What is protecting people from falling victim to a truly malicious Flash advertisement, specifically designed to overlay real content and fields and capture user entries?

Comment: Please, don't flag this question for close.  Especially don't flag it for close because it is "Off topic"  You really need to have advanced programming skills with ActionScript, JavaScript, and a clever mind to answer this question.  I suppose it is a security related question, but I believe someone with the right programming skillset can answer whether it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so you are aware, flash running in a page can communicate to JavaScript via `ExternalInterface`

This allows the programmer to run any JavaScript code they would like (especially because flash can call the `eval` function in JavaScript).

*Any* flash running on the page has the ability to set a JavaScript event handler on the username/password fields of a form and capture the values entered. The flash program could then do whatever it wanted with the data.

If the site you're logging into has flash advertisements on the login page, it's no longer a secure login. This is also true of any other form/page data. Does your online banking run flash advertisements?

Edit to clarify:

> Can an Adobe Flash advertisement capture user account name and password for a site hosting the advertisement?

## Yes

Comment: Wow!  This sounds even worse.  I hadn't thought about it like that.  So you are saying that if a site establishes a cross domain policy with an advertisement server, and that ad service subcontracts the creation of Flash advertisements to untrustworthy developers, those developers could create a Flash application that injects JavaScript into the host site?  That's even less detectable than masking the real text fields!!!

Comment: I just re-read your post and this comment got me to jumping... "If the site you're logging into has flash advertisements on the login page, it's no longer a secure login."  I logged into my bank's website where I'd recently seen an annoying banner on my checking account page.  I watched the http requests through a proxy monitor and the banner is coming from a 3rd party server.  So, you're saying that my bank has essentially opened a back-door to my checking account data. They may not even realize the potential for the ad to cull data from my checking account page?

Comment: @Michael that's exactly why I am planning on changing banks, my current bank insists on going paperless, but does not have an acceptably secure website. XSS is powerful stuff.

Comment: Using an adblocker may help prevent the possibility of flash based XSS, if it's coming from an advertisement.

Answer (score 0):

Oh it is simple isn't it? The website that the advert was running is not trustworthy.

Websites have policies with the big **I Agree** buttons (which people skip out so often) during registration. This is to gain user's trust that his/her personal info will not be shared & you may sue them if they break their policy.....Well that's a common clause anyway.

So my point is, If a website wishes they may use your stuff as they wish anyway. So if they intend to trick you by placing adverts like these then it is simply equivalent to sharing your info without your knowledge.

Comment: The website was NOT an intentionally untrustworthy site.  Their primary business is real estate; however, like most sites today they established a cross domain policy with a 3rd party advertisement service.  And, they don't directly control the advertisements presented in allotted spaces.  I strongly suspect that this business wasn't even aware that someone designed an ad that overlaid (thus copied) their content to create the clever advertisement.  The question is still open due to the programming technicality and security side of it.  Is there no security model in place to stop this tactic?

Comment: The security model to stop this is called a **sandbox**. The secure way to add 3rd party content to your website is via an iframe. The content within the iframe is in its own sandbox, and has no access to the main page's content. Also, the main page has no access to the iframes content.

Comment: So, the iframe technique can stop javascript injection you mentioned earlier, but does it constrain a clever ad as I described so that it cannot overlay content, possibly allowing the application to sneakily capture a mouse click and get focus for capture keypresses?